# Map some keystroke combination to the arrows

Tags: windows, eclipse, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm tired of moving my hands to reach for the arrows in the keyboard. So I'd really like to be able to use something like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+{<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>} to do the same as the {<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>} keys, respectively.

Having this configured under Windows for Eclipse would be enough for my use case, but is there a general solution for Windows? How about Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use Preferences -> General -> Keys to bind the keys to whatever you want.  You want to find Next Column, Previous Column, Line Down, etc.  Use the search box in the preference dialog to look for the command names.